# change default cursor style in PIXI.js

Tags: javascript, css, pixi.js

I want to change my cursor when triggering a `mousedown` event. I found a lot of hints how to achieve that - but these have one major issue. To change the `defaultCursorStyle` property I need to instantiate the `InteractionManager` prototype.

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(640, 480),
var interactionManager = new PIXI.interaction.InteractionManager(renderer)
interactionManager.defaultCursorStyle = "crosshair" // a native html/css cursor style
```

That looks fine at first but the problem here is that this InteractionManager seems to batch-register all events applied to PIXI object via the `.on(event, callback)` event-binding function *per* instance.

That means that if there would be a second instance of this `InteractionManager`, all events would be bound twice and therefore triggered twice. I had this exact issue.

So I needed to revert my changes and try to access the *default* `InteractionManager`. Somebody in the HTML5GameDev forum told me to access it like this:

```
renderer.plugins.interaction
```

knowing that I tried the following:

```
renderer.plugins.interaction.defaultCursorStyle = "crosshair"
```

My events now worked properly again. But the cursor change did not happen. However debugging the line told me that the property `defaultCursorStyle` was successfully set to `"crosshair"`. Now I'm looking for a way to make this change visible.

### My question:

Is there a better way to change the cursor style than the mentioned one above? If no, how can I make my default cursor change visible after setting the new style to the default `InteractionManager`?

Comment: On mobile so difficult to check now, but: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/master/src/interaction/InteractionManager.js says that the defaultCursor is used on next update and there is an update method, try that?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [setCursorMode](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.interaction.InteractionManager.html#setCursorMode) method in the docs, guess it's what you need.

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({ height, width })
app.renderer.plugins.interaction.cursorStyles.default = 'crosshair'

setTimeout(() => {
  app.renderer.plugins.interaction.setCursorMode('pointer')
}, 1000)
```

Whenever cursor leaves the `renderer`, PIXI resets cursor mode (here's exactly the [line](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/dcfff1505bfb9f9258bee677a6cfda5f15a9ab85/packages/interaction/src/InteractionManager.js#L1529)). So you might want to set new cursor mode as default each time you change it.

```
function changeCursorMode (cursorMode) {
  app.renderer.plugins.interaction.cursorStyles.default = cursorMode
  app.renderer.plugins.interaction.setCursorMode(cursorMode)
}

app.renderer.plugins.interaction.cursorStyles.crosshair = 'crosshair'
changeCursorMode('crosshair')
```